# Call to undefined function echo json_encode() windows easy php

Tags: php, easyphp

I installled EasyPhp Devserver and when I try to call json_encode() in my php I get the following error:

*Call to undefined function echo json_encode()*

I tried to check the output of the phpinfp.php but it seems that json is installend. Alos easyphp provides a dashboard where you can test your php code and when I call json_encode() there it works. I am using windows 10. Can anybody suggest a solution here?

Comment: Show your full code, please?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Full code: <?php echo json_encode("ddd"); ?>

Comment: LoL. That's crazy... What does `<?php var_dump(function_exists("json_encode")); ?>` give?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry for the late reply. It gives true

Comment: Looks like it should work. There's something somewhere problematic.